# Difference between TWFE DiD and "treat/post regression" DiD with time varying covariates

Tags: fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I want to estimate the effect of d on y using a simple 2x2 DiD model with a balanced panel (I observe treatment and control group before and after treatment). I suspect that parallel trends are more plausible with a time-varying covariate X, so I want to control for this. Running a TWFE regression (equation 1) with individual and time fixed effects and an indicator D equal to one when the treatment group is in the second period yields very different results than the "classical" implementation (equation 2). Without X, the results are the same. I know that time-varying covariates can be a problem if they affect treatment or vice versa, but independently, does anyone know or can explain why the estimation of D_it and treat_i*post_t are not the same? (In my case, the TWFE estimate is 10 times larger). I haven't found an explanation for it on the Internet, and I can't wrap my head around it

```
Y_it= individual_i + time_t + D_it + X_it (1)
Y_it= treat_i + post_t + treat_i*post_t + X_it (2)
```